# Pythonic way to use range with excluded last number?

Tags: python, range

If I wanted a list from 0 to 100 in steps of five I could use `range(0,105,5)`, but I could also use `range(0,101,5)`.

Honestly, neither of these makes sense to me because excluding the last number seems non-intuitive.

That aside, what is the "correct" way to create a list from 0 to 100 in steps of five? And if anyone has the time, in what instance would excluding the last number make code easier to read?

Comment: This is old CS stuff: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two choices you have listed are not similar. One is `range(start, stop+step, step)` and the other is `range(start, stop+1, step)`. They don't necessary return the same thing. The only case they do is when `stop - start` is divisible by `step`.

```
>>> start, stop, step = 0, 42, 5
>>> range(start, stop+step, step)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
>>> range(start, stop+1, step)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
```

So, which one should you use? If you want [start, stop] (inclusive), then use `stop+1` for the end of the range. Anything more than `stop+1` will have side effects like the above. `range(0, 42+5, 5)` includes 45 as a result, which is not in the [0, 42] range. How do you feel about that?

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function works like this:

```
i = lowerBound
while True:
     if(i < upperBound):
         range_list.append(i)
         i += step
     else:
         break
```

This is why `range(0, 105, 5) == range(0, 101, 5)`

and the correct way for exclude upperBound :

```
range(lowerBound, upperBound+step, step)
```

From Python doc:

> The full form returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step,
>   start + 2 * step, ...].

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to create a list from 0 to 100 in steps of five is

```
range(0, 100, 5)
```

this list has `100 / 5 == 20` elements and does not include the number `100`.

Dijkstra explained why counting should start at zero and intervals should be half-open a (very?) long time ago: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Since Python's range follows Dijkstra and uses half-open intervals, it follows that to create one past the half open interval you must add one:

```
range(0, 100+1, 5)  # closed interval [0..100] by five
```

and, yes, I would expect to see it written exactly like that in production code since it is unusual.

Comment: But he wants [0,100] not [0,100).

Comment: @jarmod he probably doesn't (it's usually a bug), but I've included how he can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could define your range function with including the upper value and then using it in your code:

```
def range_with_stop(start, stop, step):
     return range(start, stop + step, step)

In [201]: print(list(range_with_end(0, 100, 5)))
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
```

**EDIT**

According to the @Reti43 answer you could change that function to following (because I think that for that case as @Reti43 mentioned you want range(0, 40, 5) returned):

```
def range_with_stop(start, stop, step):
    if stop//step == 0:
        return(range(start, stop + step, step))
    else:
        return(range(start, step * (stop//step), step))

In [265]: range_with_stop(start, 42, step)
Out[265]: range(0, 40, 5)

In [266]: range_with_stop(start, 45, step)
Out[266]: range(0, 45, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to compute the size of the sequence based on the parameters to the range() function call, you should use `range(0,105,5)`. Consider the following:

`len(range(0,6,1)) == 6 == 6/1`

`len(range(0,6,2)) == 3 == 6/2`

`len(range(0,6,3)) == 2 == 6/3`

`len(range(0,6,4)) == 1 == floor(6/4)`

By that token, you would have

`len(range(0,105,5)) == 21 == 105/5`